# What is Ubuntu's IP reassembly timeout?

Tags: networking, ip

I've been told the IP reassembly timeout is 30 seconds, but I just need some clarification please

It'll be great if it was from Ubuntu too, as I need to reference it!

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The [TCP reassembly time in the Linux kernel](http://www.linuxinsight.com/proc_sys_net_ipv4_ipfrag_time.html) is indeed 30 seconds by default.

You can check the setting on your system by looking at:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ipfrag_time
```

You can change the timeout as well:

```
echo 60 | sudo tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ipfrag_time
```

To make the change permanent, add to your `/etc/sysctl.conf` (or a new file in `/etc/sysctl.d` directory) (`sudo` required to edit these files):

```
net.ipv4.ipfrag_time = 60
```

and run `sudo sysctl -p` to apply the change immediately.